# Bulbflow Neo4j Index Lookup Error - Multiple results on lookup with unique key

Tags: python, indexing, neo4j, lookup, bulbs

A node with record class is stored with a unique record_id. The class definition for a record is this:

```
    class BaseRecord(Node):
     element_type = "baserecord"

     rec_id = Integer(nullable=False,unique=True)
     name = String(nullable=False)

    class Record(BaseRecord):
     element_type = "record"

     rec_type = String(nullable=False)
```

The following code is run to lookup nodes using rec_id as the key.

```
    for i in range(6153713,6153717):
     records = mmidata.graph_db.record.index.lookup("rec_id",i)
     if records != None:
      print "Index Lookup - ",i, list(records)
     else:
      print "Index Lookup - ",i,records
     script = "g.V.filter{it.element_type=="+"\"record\""+"}.filter{it.rec_id=="+str(i)+"}" 
     print "Executing:",script
     records = mmidata.graph_db.gremlin.query(script)
     if records != None:
      print "Gremlin Result - ",i, list(records)
     else:
      print "Gremlin Result - ",i,records
```

At 6153713, two records are retrieved by lookup, including that for rec_id=6153714 while the gremlin query returns a single result. This is the result of the code execution.

```
Index Lookup -  6153713 [<Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5684>, <Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25977>]
Executing: g.V.filter{it.element_type=="record"}.filter{it.rec_id==6153713}
Gremlin Result -  6153713 [<Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5684>]

Index Lookup -  6153714 [<Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25977>]
Executing: g.V.filter{it.element_type=="record"}.filter{it.rec_id==6153714}
Gremlin Result -  6153714 [<Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25977>]

Index Lookup -  6153715 [<Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25978>]
Executing: g.V.filter{it.element_type=="record"}.filter{it.rec_id==6153715}
Gremlin Result -  6153715 [<Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25978>]

Index Lookup -  6153716 [<Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25979>]
Executing: g.V.filter{it.element_type=="record"}.filter{it.rec_id==6153716}
Gremlin Result -  6153716 [<Record: http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/25979>]
```

What could be the cause of this error?